# How are Delphi libraries typically installed?

Tags: delphi, autoconf

I come from a UNIX/autoconf/C/C++ background where the typical install process for a new library looks something like:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

I'm trying to install the Delphi Web Script library from: https://code.google.com/p/dwscript/ however, I cannot find installation instructions. The FirstSteps wiki page starts with:

"If DelphiWebScript is installed correctly, a new tab "dws" appears in your Delphi component palette."

Comment: In this case (I presume, never having actually done it) you check out the source from the repo. You compile the packages (.dpk files). You install the design time packages into your IDE. For runtime you use either runtime packages, or compile the source directly into your program.

Comment: Autoconf is about setting up conditional compiles and checking for dependencies. No real equivalent exists to it in Delphi. if dependencies must be edited, or options are set before building (from the IDE) you might find them in an include (*.inc) file.

Answer (score 3):

If there's a project-group file for your Delphi version, open that in the IDE. If there is no project group, but there's more than one project, consider creating a group. If there's only one project file, then just open it by itself.

Choose the "build all" menu option. For each design-time package, invoke the "install" command on it.

If there is no project file, then consider creating one for the source files you have. Otherwise, put them in with the rest of your main project's files. (My rule is that every source file is a member of one and only one project.)

Most source files that don't come with a project are for *components*, so the type of project you'd create for them would be a *package*. Source files meant to be used as DLLs generally come with a library-project file.

Comment: Certain versions of Delphi (XE and higher) show the difference between Designtime and Runtime-Only packages as a different icon.  For designtime packages, many begin with "dcl" in the filename. So "dclMyPackage180.dpk" is the designtime, and "MyPackage180.dpk" is runtime.